# How to inject custom meta tags in html-webpack-plugin?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, html-webpack-plugin

I use Webpack along with the plugin `html-webpack-plugin`. Based on an environment variable, I want to inject a `<meta></meta>` tag into the final `index.html` file.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can define your own template. It's briefly mentioned in [Writing Your Own Templates](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#writing-your-own-templates) that you can pass any options you'd like to it and use them in the template with `htmlWebpackPlugin.options`:

> `htmlWebpackPlugin.options`: the options hash that was passed to the plugin. In addition to the options actually used by this plugin, you can use this hash to pass arbitrary data through to your template.

For example you could define the author with the environment variable `AUTHOR` and add an `author` option to the plugin:

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: 'template.ejs',
  author: process.env.AUTHOR
})
```

In your `template.ejs` you can create a `<meta>` tag with that information:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <% if (htmlWebpackPlugin.options.author) { %>
    <meta name="author" content="<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.author %>">
    <% } %>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

You could use a `.html` file instead and the plugin will fallback to `ejs-loader`, but if you have `html-loader` configured for `.html` files, it will use that instead of the fallback, so the embedding won't work.

When `AUTHOR` is set it will include the meta tag with the author, otherwise it's not included. Running:

```
AUTHOR='Foo Bar' webpack
```

will include the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="author" content="Foo Bar">
```

Comment: great, this is what i was after :)

Answer (score 11):

```
   new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
     template: 'index.html',
     meta: {
       author: process.env.AUTHOR
     }
   });
```

resulting in the inclusion of the following within your head tag.

`<meta name="author" content="Foo Bar">`

Answer (score 2):

Try [html-webpack-tags-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-tags-plugin)

```js
new HtmlWebpackTagsPlugin({
    metas: [{
        path: 'img/logo.png',
        attributes: {
            property: 'og:image'
        }
    },{
        attributes: {
            property: 'og:image:type',
            content: "image/png"
        }
    },{
        attributes: {
            property: 'og:image:width',
            content: "200"
        }
    },{
        attributes: {
            property: 'og:image:height',
            content: "200"
        }
    },]
}),
```

Comment: it's not loading my image

Answer (score 2):

Following on @Will, in addition to name/content meta tags the value can be an object.  The key/values of the object will be assigned to the meta tag.

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    template: 'index.html',
    meta: {
        someName: {
            httpEquiv: 'Content-Language',
            content: 'en_US'
        },
        anotherName: { 
            key: 'description',
            content: 'description goes here'
        }
    }
})
```

`<meta key="description" content="description goes here">`

`<meta httpEquiv="Content-Language" content="en_US">`