# Custom properties in Webpack 2 Config

Tags: javascript, angular, webpack, webpack-2

In webpack1, I was able to use custom properties to declare a variable "metadata" which consists information that would be extracted in `index.html`.

In webpack.common.js, under `module.exports` , i had `metadata: METADATA` where `METADATA` has title, host etc.

In index.html , I was able to do this,

```
<title><%= webpackConfig.metadata.title %></title>
```

This way the title would be displayed in the browser tab when the app ran. But now I am unable to send the `metadata` across to `index.html` and title does not get displayed, as `webpack2` does not support a property called `metadata`.

What is the work around to sending this data to `index.html`?

Comment: Are you using [`html-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)? If you are using it, you can have a look at [How to inject custom meta tags in html-webpack-plugin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018983/how-to-inject-custom-meta-tags-in-html-webpack-plugin).

Comment: And if it's just to insert a title, there's a title option you can pass when initiating the plugin

Comment: @MichaelJungo It doesnt seem to recognizing `htmlWebpackPlugin.options` in `index.html`. I'm using `raw-loader` for `.html` files. Should I use `html-loader`?

Comment: This syntax is [EJS](https://github.com/mde/ejs) and `html-webpack-plugin` will fallback to an `ejs-loader` if you haven't configured any loader for that file. It's best to use a `.ejs` template, so you can still have your regular loaders for HTML. Or you can use any other template engine that supports this kind of interpolation (e.g. Pug) with the appropriate loader. See also [How can I use handlebars/pug/ejs as template engine](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin/blob/master/docs/template-option.md).