# How to inject meta tag in html using webpack?

Tags: html, webpack, webpack-4

I'm trying to inject meta tag in html using `html webpack plugin` and I can't find a way how to inject meta tag like :

- `<meta property="foo" content="bar">`

The example available in doc about it not clear:
https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin#meta-tags

it dealing with all meta tags like they are all about `name` `content` e.g:

```
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template:'./src/home.html',
            filename: "index.html",
            meta: {
                property: 'foo', 
                author: 'Ayman Morsy'
        }
```

will parse it like :

- `<meta name="property" content="foo">` // This is wrong meta how to correct it ?
- `<meta name="author" content="Ayman Morsy">`

Comment: I don't think the `meta` option supports what you're after. Consider following this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018983/how-to-inject-custom-meta-tags-in-html-webpack-plugin

Comment: @sdgluck thanks, I saw this Q and because I'm using `bugjs`  I found mixins helpful with  HTMLWebpackPlugin meta. I wished if I can do this job from one place